# Limiting input frequency to a specified value

Tags: frequency, sine

I would like to limit the output frequency of a variable reluctance differential signal to a specified value, in this case 7,000 Hz. It is a constant peak-to-peak of 24.0 V, which remains unchanged throughout the frequency range. This signal comes from a crankshaft position sensor on an engine, and has a "missing tooth" behavior where regardless of frequency, after 34 cycles there is a missing period in the signal.

I am unsure if the missing tooth behavior is necessary for this application, however I would like to know if it is possible.

The output frequency needs to match that of the input until 7,000 Hz, above which it remains at a constant 7,000 Hz and the input is allowed to rise above 7k.

The signal cannot attenuate and the frequency cannot rise above the cutoff point.

Thanks!

Devon

Comment: That doesn't sound easy.  Maybe a PLL with a clamp on the VCO voltage, but the devil is in the details.

Comment: How fast a response time is required, what is the threshold for the 7 kHz (1 Hz, 0.1 Hz, etc.), and what accuracy do you want? Also, how fast is the input frequency changing? The response time cannot be 0 so there will be an output frequency overshoot.

Comment: Smells of XY - please explain why you feel you need this functionality.

Comment: Super precision isn't really necessary, this is an automotive application and I am limiting the tachometer signal to 7,000 RPM while allowing the engine to rev past that. In this case the input frequency is changing on the order of 500 Hz / second.

Answer (score 2):

You basically need an MCU or FPGA that reads the input signal and monitors the frequency, zero cross and missing teeth.

Then it producess an output signal with a 24V DAC so that it is either a copy of the input, or a 7kHz sine wave where the first zero cross lines up with that of the last input signal befire it exceeded 7kHz and where and a new missing tooth is generated in a free-running mode every 34 cycles counting backwards to the last missing tooth detected before the input signal exceeded 7kHz.

When switching from < 7kHz to >7kHz you would start the generate 7kHz limited sine at zero when the input crosses zero to align the zero-crossings for smooth transition.

It will be inelegant switching from >7kHz back to <7kHz unless you program it to quickly sweep the >7kHz generated output back toward the <7kHz input frequency until zero-crosses align at which pont you switch to just making a reproduction of the input.

Comment: This was one of my original ideas, however the waveform contains information in the form of a missing "tooth" which equates to a missing period in the signal every 34 cycles. I would like to retain this information, however i'm sure there's a way to generate this type of behavior.

Comment: @DevonFreeland That's CRITICAL information you left out of your original post which changes the fundamental nature of your entire question and makes everyone's answer invalid. Your signal is an arbitrary signal, not a sinusoid. Furthermore you have not described at all how you expect the missing tooth be passed to the output while simultaneously changing the entire signal so that the sine-shapey parts don't exceed 7kHz, which is mutually exclusive. This sounds like a "have-your cake-and-eat it too" situation.

Comment: My apologies, I appreciate everyone's responses. The missing "tooth" behavior above 7kHz should match the previous signal. As in, every 34 cycles there must be a missing period in the signal regardless of frequency. This missing tooth behavior allows the engine computer to know what angle the crankshaft is in, therefore determining timing.

Comment: @DevonFreeland This sounds like an X-Y problem. How can anything match the previous signal when it's being clamped to 7kHz when what is going in is not 7kHz? Ever 34 cycles at the input has zero correlation to every 34 cycles at the output if the signals are completely different (which they pretty much are if the input is >7kHz and the output is 7kHz). What is it you are trying to do by limiting it to 7kHz? You are probably going to need to provide sketches of what you want to appear on the output for an input of >7kHz with missing teeth.

Comment: @DevonFreeland Did you want it to run in a "free-running" mode after the frequency exceeds 7kHz with it adding a missing tooth pulse every 34 cycles counting from the number of cycles the last missing tooth was detected before the signal exceeded 7kHz? Because that's really, really tricky, especially if you need to keep it as a sine-wave. Would be much easier if you turned it into a square wave. Can the computer accept square waves instead of sine waves?

Comment: A free running mode is a great way to put it, and yes that is what needs to happen. It cannot accept square waves to my knowledge, even if they are differential. This is an OEM computer so there is no modification to the internals, it basically needs to be fed what it wants to see in order to be happy.

Comment: If we ignore the missing tooth issue for now, would your original comment about using a SPDT switch and a waveform generator still apply?

Comment: @DevonFreeland Yes, but there is a discontinuity when switching to and from. If you control the 7kHz source it is possible to start it at zero crossing so switching to it is seamless, but you don't have the same luxury when switching from it.

Comment: @DevonFreeland For your whole missing tooth system you basically need an MCU OR FPGA that reads the input signal, and then reproduces another signal with a 24V DAC. It might still be inelegant switching from >7kHz back to your original source unless you program it to quickly sweep back to the input frequency, have it lock on and then switch over. Not really really tricky like I originally said, but certainly more involved than what you may have been expecting.

Comment: Sounds good! You're right in that I was hoping that there could be a more elegant solution to the problem, but hopefully your idea will work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This will not be possible with a low-pass filter which (gradually) attenuates the signal as it approaches the cut-off frequency, reaches -3 dB at the cut-off frequency and, for frequencies above cut-off, continues to fall at a rate determined by the filter. The reduced output will have the same frequency as the input.

If you edit your question to explain the real problem you are trying to solve further help should arrive.

Comment: Edited my post for clarity.

Comment: ... but without explaining the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you measure, using a counter with 10 nanoSecond time resolution, the period from zero_crossing to zero_crossing, you can then switch to an internally_generated sinusoid of frequency 7,000.000 Hz.

And using moderate speed logic, you can make this switch within 10 or 20nanoSecond of the "early" zero_crossing.

You may have to accept imperfect amplitudes or harmonics or phase glitches.